# I want to download multiple file from site using selenium webdriver which is having dropdown values (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
obj =  Select(driver.find_element_by_name("DdlState"))
obj1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("DdlYear"))

obj.select_by_value('35')
obj1.select_by_value('2008')
```

I want to download multiple files for every dropdown values in excel format
file download for  'classification of Area'

URL = 'https://aps.dac.gov.in/LUS/Public/Reports.aspx'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to download multiple file from site using selenium which is having dropdown values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046654/i-want-to-download-multiple-file-from-site-using-selenium-which-is-having-dropdo)

Comment: its not working

Comment: I want to download files using selenium web driver by selecting dropdown values .URL has multiple dropdown values.